# parse before 2 tag beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to extract all links http://example.com/1 and ignore all link after 2 `<br><br>` tag with beautifulsoup.

```
<div class="compost">
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index18" class="select_index"></span>text 2</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index19" class="select_index"></span>text 3</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index20" class="select_index"></span>text 4</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index21" class="select_index"></span>text 5</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index22" class="select_index"></span>text 6</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index23" class="select_index"></span>text 7</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index24" class="select_index"></span>text 8</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index25" class="select_index"></span>text 9</a></b>
<br>
<br>
<b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index18" class="select_index"></span>text 2</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index19" class="select_index"></span>text 3</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index20" class="select_index"></span>text 4</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index21" class="select_index"></span>text 5</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index22" class="select_index"></span>text 6</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index23" class="select_index"></span>text 7</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index24" class="select_index"></span>text 8</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index25" class="select_index"></span>text 9</a></b>
<br>
<br>
<b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/3"><span id="s_index18" class="select_index"></span>text 2</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/3"><span id="s_index19" class="select_index"></span>text 3</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/3"><span id="s_index20" class="select_index"></span>text 4</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/3"><span id="s_index21" class="select_index"></span>text 5</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/3"><span id="s_index22" class="select_index"></span>text 6</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/3"><span id="s_index23" class="select_index"></span>text 7</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/3"><span id="s_index24" class="select_index"></span>text 8</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/3"><span id="s_index25" class="select_index"></span>text 9</a></b>
<br>
<br>
```

here is part i need to parse:

```
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index18" class="select_index"></span>text 2</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index19" class="select_index"></span>text 3</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index20" class="select_index"></span>text 4</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index21" class="select_index"></span>text 5</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index22" class="select_index"></span>text 6</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index23" class="select_index"></span>text 7</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index24" class="select_index"></span>text 8</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index25" class="select_index"></span>text 9</a></b>
```

here is part of my code

```
    for links in obja.find_all("div", class_="compost"):
        if links.has_attr('href'):
            print links['href']
        #
        aa = links.findAll('a')[0]
        print aa.attrs['href']
        txt = []
        for i in links.findAll('br'):
            txt.append(i.text)
            print i.nextSibling
            if i.nextSibling.text != u'br':
                txt.append(i.nextSibling.text)

        ''.join(txt)
```

my script extract all links and i don't know how i can extract just all http://example.com/1 and ignore all links after `<br><br>`?

Comment: Can you just ignore all other links and only grab `a` tags with an `href` of `http://example.com/1`? `obja.find_all('a', attrs={'href': 'http://example.com/1'})`

Comment: @GregReda, i can't because links have same domain, it's used for redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just find the first `<br><br>` and search for hrefs in only that substring.

Like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """
<div class="compost">
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index18"      class="select_index"></span>text 2</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index19" class="select_index"></span>text 3</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index20" class="select_index"></span>text 4</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index21" class="select_index"></span>text 5</a></b>
 <br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index22" class="select_index"></span>text 6</a></b>
 <br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index23" class="select_index"></span>text 7</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index24" class="select_index"></span>text 8</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/1"><span id="s_index25" class="select_index"></span>text 9</a></b>
<br>
<br>
<b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index18" class="select_index"></span>text 2</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index19" class="select_index"></span>text 3</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index20" class="select_index"></span>text 4</a></b>
 <br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index21" class="select_index"></span>text 5</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index22" class="select_index"></span>text 6</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index23" class="select_index"></span>text 7</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index24" class="select_index"></span>text 8</a></b>
<br><b><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/2"><span id="s_index25" class="select_index"></span>text 9</a></b>
<br>
<br>
...."""

br_split = example[0: example.index("<br>\n<br>")]

soup = BeautifulSoup(br_split, "html.parser")

print (soup.find_all("a"))
```

Outputs:
[image: Output]

Comment: thanks for your instructive example, it's strange, I never saw an index like that.